# How to connect to Microsft SQL Sever 2005 in another pc using pyodbc?

Tags: python, sql-server, database, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to a database, from a Windows 10, that is on another pc in the same local network using the pyodbc module. The external pc is a Windows Server 2003 and it has a database Microsoft SQL Server 2005. I am not sure how the connection string has to be, I have tried with the following code:

```
import pyodbc

DRIVER = "{ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server}" # supports SQL Server 2005 through 2014
SERVER = "192.168.100.101" # the ip of the windows server 2003
PORT = "1433" # I am not sure if this parameter is needed
DATABASE = "database_name" # name of the database
USER = "user"
PASS = "psw"

string_connection = f"DRIVER={DRIVER};SERVER={SERVER};PORT={PORT};DATABASE={DATABASE};UID={USER};PWD={PASS}"

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(string_connection)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

cursor.close()
cnxn.close()
```

But when I run the code above I get the following error:

> InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Comment: Is that ODBC driver installed? Run odbcad32.exe and click the drivers tab to verify.

Comment: In the pc with Windows 10 or in the one with Windows Server 2003?

Comment: The client Windows 10 box.

Comment: It does not have it installed, it has SQL Server and SQL Server Native Client 10.0...

Comment: You can probably just use the native client driver instead. This is the [ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Data source name not found and no default driver specified

This error message indicates the driver specified in the connection string is not installed on the client machine. Run odbcad32.exe on the Win10 machine and click the drivers tab to view the list of installed ODBC drivers.

To remediate, you can either change the connection string to use an already installed SQL Server ODBC driver, or install the ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434).

Be aware that Windows Server 2003 and SQL Server 2005 have been out of support for several years. The oldest support Windows server version is 2012 and SQL 2012 is the oldest SQL version as of this writing. I suggest you migrate to newer versions.